# App: prop type `store` is invalid; it must be a function, usually from the `prop-types` package, but received `undefined`

Tags: reactjs, mobx, react-proptypes

I have a react with mobx app and I get the following error message in the console:

> App: prop type `store` is invalid; it must be a function, usually from
>   the `prop-types` package, but received `undefined`

The code looks like this:

```
import React, {PureComponent} from 'react';
import {observer, PropTypes} from 'mobx-react';

// Some other imports

const propTypes = {
    store: PropTypes.object
};

@observer
class App extends PureComponent {
    // Some lifecycle and class functions here

    render() {
       // Render implementation here
    }
}

App.propTypes = propTypes;
export default App;
```

The `index.js` file looks like this:

```
// Some imports here...

ReactDOM.render(<App store={store} />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mobx-react` [exports](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react#proptypes) in PropTypes types specific to mobx only.

So, to use React PropTypes, try to import them from `prop-types` package as usual:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {PropTypes as MobxPropTypes} from 'mobx-react';
```

And then if you need to use types from Mobx, you can use `MobxPropTypes`

Comment: `React.PropTypes` is deprecated. `prop-types` package is the way to go. `import PropTypes from 'prop-types'`

Comment: @cfraser - indeed, that's what I had to do at the end.

Comment: iofjuupasli - want to update the answer so I'll accept it?